# How to change my connected graph in C++ so that each vertices can hold an object?

Tags: c++

I am implementing a simple game board using connected graph in C++. Each vertice represents a place to put a building object. My teammate is working on the building class and he said my graph doesn't hold data. I am new to C++ so can anyone show me how to modify my code so that it can hold building objects? Thank you so much.

My code:

VGMap.h

```
#ifndef VGMAP_H
#define VGMAP_H

namespace Board
{
  struct AdjListNode{    
    int data;
    AdjListNode *next;
  };
  struct AdjList{
    AdjListNode *head;
  };
  struct Graph{
    int V;
    AdjList *arr;
  };
  class Vgmap{
    public:
      static AdjListNode *newAdjListNode(int);
      static Graph *createGraph(int);
      static void addEdge(Graph*,int,int);
      static void printGraph(Graph*);
  };
}
#endif
```

VGMap.cpp

```
#include "VGMap.h"    

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

namespace Board
{
  AdjListNode* Vgmap::newAdjListNode(int data){
    AdjListNode *nptr=new AdjListNode;
    nptr->data=data;
    nptr->next=NULL;
    return nptr;

  }
  Graph* Vgmap::createGraph(int V){
    Graph *graph=new Graph;
    graph->V=V;
    //create an array of adjacency list. size of array - V
    graph->arr=new AdjList[V];
    //initialize with NULL (e.g root=NULL)
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
        graph->arr[i].head=NULL;
    }
    return graph;
  }

  void Vgmap::addEdge(Board::Graph *graph, int src, int dest){
    AdjListNode *nptr=newAdjListNode(dest);
    nptr->next=graph->arr[src].head;
    graph->arr[src].head=nptr;
    //connect from dest to src (since undirected)
    nptr=newAdjListNode(src);
    nptr->next=graph->arr[dest].head;
    graph->arr[dest].head=nptr;
  }

void Vgmap::printGraph(Board::Graph* graph){
//loop over each adjacent list
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("VGMap.txt");
myfile <<"The value for each vertice:"<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<graph->V;i++){
        AdjListNode *root=graph->arr[i].head;
        if(i==4||(i-4)%5==0){
          myfile <<std::endl;
        }
        else if(i%5==0){
          myfile <<i<<" ";
        }
        while(root!=NULL){
          if(root->data==i+1){
            myfile <<root->data<<" ";
            //i=i+1;
          }
            root=root->next;
        }
    }
myfile <<std::endl;
    myfile.close();
}
}
```

VGMapDriver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

#include "VGMap.h"
#include "VGMap.cpp"

using Board::AdjListNode;
using Board::AdjList;
using Board::Graph;
using Board::Vgmap;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
  int totalVertices=30;
    Graph *graph;
    graph=Vgmap::createGraph(totalVertices);
    //connect edge
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=5;i<9;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=10;i<14;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=15;i<19;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=20;i<24;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i+1);
    }
    for(int i=29;i>25;i--){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,i,i-1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,25-i*5,25-(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,1+i*5,1+(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,2+i*5,2+(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,3+i*5,3+(i+1)*5);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      Vgmap::addEdge(graph,4+i*5,4+(i+1)*5);
    }
    Vgmap::printGraph(graph);
}
```

Comment: What kind of data is your node currently holding? Change it to be a `Building` instead.

Comment: @John, the int attribute data is just a number for each node, but a Building is an object created in another class Building, which includes attributes building type, color, and size. So can I simply add an attribute with type Building?

Comment: What is the number on each node used for? If you don't need it, replace it with `Building`. If you do need the int, then keep it and add a `Building` object as well to each node.

Comment: @John, Oh, thanks. So that means my graph is actually able to hold Building objects, and the reason my teammate said my graph doesn't hold object is simply because I didn't add the attribute Building right?

Comment: that's a reasonable interpretation of why they said that. In the end, only your team mate can tell you why they said it. Ask them.

Comment: @John, ok, thank u so much.